# Pipe executed command into the same output file of the command

Tags: windows, command-line, cmd.exe

I've had a look at various tips ([ss64.com Command Redirection](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html)) and tricks but couldn't find an answer to my question:

## Question

Is it possible to pipe the command I am going to execute into the same redirected output I will be creating?

## Example with netstat

### Input command

```
C:\Users\memyselfandi> netstat -obna >C:\temp\netstat_with_programs.txt
```

The actual command would be: `netstat -obna >C:\temp\netstat_with_programs.txt`

### Output (The text file netstat_with_programs.txt)

This is the actual content of the `netstat_with_programs.txt` file. (*The command is basically documenting itself in the output file.*)

```
netstat -obna >C:\temp\netstat_with_programs.txt
Active connections

  Proto  Local Address          Remoteaddress          State             PID
  TCP    0.0.0.0:135            0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING         888
  RpcSs
 [svchost.exe]
  TCP    0.0.0.0:2382           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING         1396
 [sqlbrowser.exe]
  TCP    0.0.0.0:3389           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING         376
  TermService
 [svchost.exe]
....
```

## Example with arp

### Input command

```
C:\users\memyselfandi> arp -a >C:\temp\arp_output.txt
```

The actual command is: `arp -a >C:\temp\arp_output.txt`

### Output (The contents of arp_output.txt)

This is the actual content of the `arp_output.txt` file. (*The command is basically documenting itself in the output file.*)

```
arp -a >C:\temp\arp_output.txt
Interface: 10.57.209.191 --- 0x5
  Internet Address      Physical Address      Type
  10.57.209.2           80-e0-1d-58-8a-50     dynamic 
  10.57.209.3           80-e0-1d-58-8b-88     dynamic 
  10.57.209.9           00-50-56-8d-91-fe     dynamic 
  10.57.209.10          00-50-56-8d-91-fe     dynamic 
  10.57.209.175         00-50-56-b5-44-16     dynamic 
  10.57.209.255         ff-ff-ff-ff-ff-ff     static  
  224.0.0.22            01-00-5e-00-00-16     static  
  224.0.0.252           01-00-5e-00-00-fc     static  
  230.0.0.1             01-00-5e-00-00-01     static  
  239.255.255.250       01-00-5e-7f-ff-fa     static
```

So basically I would be documenting the command I am executing in the output I am creating.

---

Based on the possible solutions provided by @barlop in the comments, I went ahead and executed both commands:

### With ECHO

```
echo netstat -obna >C:\temp\netstat_with_programs.txt && netstat -obna >>C:\temp\netstat_with_programs.txt
```

...this produced the following first line in the output file, which doesn't fully satisfy the requirements:

```
netstat -obna  
....
```

### With %aaa% variable

```
set aaa=netstat -obna
echo (%aaa%>C:\temp\netstat_with_programs.txt) && (echo %aaa%|cmd)>>C:\temp\netstat_with_programs.txt
```

...this produces the same output, which doesn't fully meet the requirements:

```
netstat -obna  
...
```

Comment: Your English is completely ambiguous  and thus not clear what you are asking. You should provide examples showing exactly what you mean. Show the contents of `C:\temp\netstat_with_programs.txt`  before and after.  Demonstrating exactly what you mean rather than trying to use your highly ambigious words.

Comment: Also your title gives no indication of exactly what you are talking about

Comment: I'd be interested to know which part of my question is ambiguous? The input is clearly stated in my question. `netstat -obna >C:\temp\netstat_with_programs.txt`. The output of my command is a text file which contains the contents outlined in the **Output** section of my question, which includes the command I executed. I don't think that my question is either ambiguous, nor syntactically, orthographically or typographically incorrect. I would appreciate if you could exactly explain which part of the question you are unable to grasp.

Comment: Because it is a `>` the file is previously non-existent. I am not adding (`>>`) to an existing file.

Comment: You have now corrected the unclear part of your question

Comment: Suppose it was the DIR command.  You could do  `echo dir >a.ra && dir >>a.ra`

Comment: another thing you could do is `set aaa=DIR` then do `echo (%aaa%>z.zz) && (echo %aaa%|cmd) >>z.zz`

Comment: I appreciate your feedback. I have tried out both suggested solutions, but the redirection isn't documented in the output file. i know the question is tricky, which is the main reason I am asking it on superuser.com, otherwise I would have solved it myself. I understand the basic concepts of `2>&1` and things like that and had tried out `0>&1` to redirect the standard input into the output, but I guess that would have to happen before I type the commands.

Answer (score 1):

This is impossible because the shell, which takes the command and executes it, has no idea of what the arguments do that it is passing to the command.

For example in our theoretical `rot13write` `C:\foobar.txt`, is `P:\sbbone.gkg`

```
rot13write -qevir "P" -svyr "sbbone" rkg ".gkg"
```

That may tell `rot13write` to write to the drive `P`, the file `foobar`, and the extension `txt`. Or it may all be a joke and that path *could* have already been hard coded into the executable. You don't know, and neither does a shell.

So the shell can **not** echo to the file that a program is mysteriously writing to, because the shell doesn't know of that sufficiently; and, the program which does know how it is invoked is under no obligation to do anything with that data (like print the invocation command to the file it's outputting to). What you can do is

1. Have the shell echo all its commands. Most shells support this.
2. Have the program that you execute write to standard output (as it normally does) which the program will inherit from the shell that spawned it (this is how programs you call and the shell write to the same place -- the psuedo terminal)
3. Redirect the shells standard output to destination file.

This will do everything you want **except** show the flag and output location in the command.

This looks like this in [command prompt (I think)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1141753/124486)

```
cmd /c "netstat" > myOutput.txt | type myOutput.txt
```

And it looks like this in PowerShell,

```
powershell -command "Set-PSDebug -Trace 1; netstat" | tee myOutput.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

If the problem is to display (or redirect to a file) the redirection symbol (`>`) with the `ECHO` command, then you just need to escape it. The escape symbol in this case would be `^`:

```
ECHO netstat -obna ^>C:\temp\netstat_with_programs.txt >C:\temp\netstat_with_programs.txt
netstat -obna >>C:\temp\netstat_with_programs.txt
```

The second command in the above snippet is using `>>` instead of `>` because you want to add the output to the same file rather than to overwrite it.

Comment: I was just starting to wonder why it didn't work, until I realised that your solution is to execute two commands. Good solution, but it breaks the flow somewhat.